# Add stickiness on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a design in stripes :

html :

```
<div class='resize' style='background-color:black;'></div>
<div class='resize' style='background-color:red;'></div>
<div class='resize' style='background-color:green;'></div>
<div class='resize' style='background-color:blue;'></div>
<div class='resize' style='background-color:grey;'></div>
```

js :

```
$(function() {
    $('.resize').css({
        'height': (($(window).height()))
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('.resize').css({
            'height': (($(window).height()))
        });
    });
});

$(window).height();
```

Here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Awt7q/

I would like to add stickiness on scrolling when the users reach a new stripe, so that when the users scroll they don't go to quickly. The stripes need to stick a bit to the top of the screen.

Here is an example of what I would like to do : http://timmytompkinsapp.com

I really don't get how I could create this stickiness effect.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Read the source code of the app you linked to. The answers are in there: specifically in the script tag in the header there's a `callbackScroll()` function that handles the movement of the page. It's pretty simple. Try and implement on your own before asking on SO. Especially when you link to the answer.

Comment: Jason is 100% correct